# How to work around stale element exception in PyTest

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, pytest

In the below test, I am clicking on each of the cards on [this link](https://ywamconverge.org/projects?locale=en) and seeing if the title text matches. I am running into a StaleElementReferenceException and my assumption is that `internships` variable becomes stale after clicking on the card even if I use `self.driver.back()` to return to the page from which I clicked.

Is there a workaround for this type of issue? Or do I need to create separate tests for each card? If so, does PyTest have a built-in module that allows us to easily create separate tests?

```
def test_internship_links(self):
    num_title_mismatch = 0
    title_mismatches = {}
    internships_xpath = (
        "//div[@id='related_projects']//div[@class='project-description']/h3"
    )
    internships = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, internships_xpath)
    for internship in internships:
        outer_title = internship.text
        internship.click()
        inner_title = self.driver.find_element(
            By.XPATH, "//div[@class='primary']//h1"
        ).text
        if inner_title != outer_title:
            num_title_mismatch += 1
            title_mismatches[outer_title] = inner_title
        self.driver.back()
    assert (
        num_title_mismatch == 0
    ), f"\n{num_title_mismatch} title mismatch(es) found:\n{title_mismatches}"
```

Error traceback:

```
________________________________________________________________________ TestSearchInterships.test_internship_links ________________________________________________________________________

self = <test_search_internships.TestSearchInterships object at 0x1081bfe90>

    def test_internship_links(self):
        num_title_mismatch = 0
        title_mismatches = {}
        internships_xpath = (
            "//div[@id='related_projects']//div[@class='project-description']/h3"
        )
        internships = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, internships_xpath)
        for internship in internships:
>           outer_title = internship.text

tests/test_search_internships.py:41: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
../../../.local/share/virtualenvs/converge-testing-PXQ7_xev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py:81: in text
    return self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_TEXT)['value']
../../../.local/share/virtualenvs/converge-testing-PXQ7_xev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py:693: in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
../../../.local/share/virtualenvs/converge-testing-PXQ7_xev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:338: in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
```

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question.

Comment: @KlausD. Added above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counting the number of elements and using a range instead of looping through the elements themselves did the trick for me. Below is the working code.

```
def test_internship_links(self):
    num_title_mismatch, title_mismatches = 0, {}
    internships = self.driver.find_elements(
        By.XPATH, "//div[@id='related_projects']//a"
    )
    # xpath is indexed from 1, not 0
    for int_num in range(1, len(internships) + 1):
        internship_xpath = f"//div[@id='related_projects']//a[{int_num}]//div[@class='project-description']//h3"
        internship = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, internship_xpath)
        outer_title = internship.text
        internship.click()
        inner_title_xpath = "//div[@class='primary']//h1"
        inner_title = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, inner_title_xpath).text
        if inner_title != outer_title:
            num_title_mismatch += 1
            title_mismatches[outer_title] = inner_title
        self.driver.back()
    assert_str = (
        f"\n{num_title_mismatch} title mismatch(es) found:\n{title_mismatches}"
    )
    assert num_title_mismatch == 0, assert_string
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem may happen if a DOM(Document Object Model) operation on the page is temporarily causing the element to be inaccessible.

I can see 2 possible workarounds for your problem.

1) Instead of using `self.driver.back()` to return to the page you can navigate again to the link. e.g.: `driver.get('your_url')`

2) You can try to access the element several times in a loop before finally throwing an exception. You can check Darrel Grainger's solution [here](http://darrellgrainger.blogspot.com/2012/06/staleelementexception.html).

Please thumb me up if I've helped somehow =)

Comment: Thanks but neither of the suggested workarounds resolved the StaleElementReferenceException error